# How to disable beep in C# for Symbol PPT2800 barcode scanner?

Tags: c#, barcode, pocketpc

I'm developing an application in C# for symbol PPT2800 barcode scanner. I'm almost done but there is one last thing I need, I want the scanner to disable the beep if the ean code was not found and make a different sound. I've been tearing my hair over this but I cant get it to work, could someone help me?

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: Here is the main program http://pastebin.com/KhYP0vh0                 I tried to silent the reader permanently to start with just to see how it's done by using this.beeper.Volume = 0;

Answer (score 1):

You need to either find the Symbol SDK (I think Motorola bought them out) or go into the Settings for the Scanner and turn the audible beep option OFF.

If you want to use the SDK, remember that you are making your program stuck to only one type of device.

Also, if it helps, a piece of clear tape (from a desktop tape dispenser) works wonders with attenuating that BEEP when you scan a barcode. Then, when you are ready to deploy the device, just peel the tape off.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing but decided not to disable the beeps in code.  As @jp2code points out, doing it with an SDK/code ties you to a single manufacturer or type of scanner.  Simply scanning the correct "setup" barcode can disable (or enable) the beep and then just play a sound using code.  I was using an LS2208 barcode reader unit, but a quick google search should find the manual for your model.