# How to control beep programmatically for Symbol MC9190 barcode scanner

Tags: c#, vb.net, barcode, pocketpc, motorola-emdk

I am developing an application for **Symbol MC9190** barcode scanner in VB.NET.

I am almost finished with the application, and now all I need is to control duration of the beep (or number of beeps) based on barcode symbology. Say, it will make one kind of beep for 1D barcode, and another for 2D.

I created a beeper object:

```
Dim NotificationDevices As Symbol.Notification.Device() = Symbol.Notification.Device.AvailableDevices()

For Each NotificationDevice As Symbol.Notification.Device In NotificationDevices
    If NotificationDevice.ObjectType = Symbol.Notification.NotifyType.BEEPER Then
        myBeeper = New Symbol.Notification.Beeper(NotificationDevice)
        Exit For
     End If
 Next
```

And I am trying to control the beeper like this:

```
   myBeeper.Duration = 1000
```

There are two problems.

First, assigning properties to myBeeper object does not seem to affect the actual sound that comes out.

Second, the scanner emits the sound **before** it raises the myReader_ReadNotify event, and so by the time I evaluate the encoding, the scanner has already beeped.

I could, possibly, mute the default beep, and force the scanner to emit the sound after I evaluate the data, but I do not see a beep event (or any other event) in the myBeeper object, and so I do not know how to force the scanner to emit the sound.

I found a similar post [How to disable beep in C# for Symbol PPT2800 barcode scanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449276/how-to-disable-beep-in-c-sharp-for-symbol-ppt2800-barcode-scanner?rq=1), but the answers were completely off topic.

Could anyone who knows how to program Symbol scanners help me out please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered on the motorola site:

https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/message/84843?et=watches.email.thread#84843

It short, the only way to implement this is to mute the default beep, and play my own .wav sound.